# (help) SqlTransaction Loop

Tags: c#, ado.net

need to get explained and clarified about SqlTransaction (s)

So the case is, based on the code below

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
con.Open();

SqlTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction();

bool IsSave = false;

for(int i = 0; i < obj.Count; i++) 
{
    IsSave = Some_Insert_Method_On_Other_Class(obj[i], con, trans);
    if (!IsSave)
    {
        trans.Rollback();
        return;
    }

    trans.Commit();
}
```

the question is, should i commit once per loop or just let it loop then commit the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

A transaction is SQL's way to bind together different statements into a single atomic operation - meaning all or nothing - if one statement fails, all the previous statements in the transaction scope are rolled back, and non of the next statements in the transaction is executed.

A transaction can end in one of two different ways - It's either commited, or rolled back. It can only be committed or rolled back once.

So, to translate that information into a direct answer to your question, the `trans.Commit();` must come after the loop. If a single save operation fails, the transaction is rolled back and you exit the method. Only if all of them succeed, you commit the transaction.

btw, Whenever possible, you should wrap all instances of classes that implements the `IDisposable` interface in a `using` statement:

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
{
    con.Open();
    using(var trans = con.BeginTransaction())
    {

    bool IsSave = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < obj.Count; i++) 
    {
        IsSave = Some_Insert_Method_On_Other_Class(obj[i], con, trans);
        if (!IsSave)
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            return;
        }
    }
    trans.Commit();
    }
}
```